# Reload laravel foreach after ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a foreach loop in my view

```
<div class="col-lg-6 collapse" >
    <div class="job-summ-panel" id="job-summ-panel" >
        @foreach($jobs as $job)
            {{$job['active']}}
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
```

I also have a Google map on the page with map markers and when I click a map marker an ajax call is made to get all the info related to the page

```
$.ajax({
    method: "get",
    url: '/joblocation/jobsummary',
    data: {
        job_ref: marker.getCustomData('job_ref'),
    },
    success: function (response) {
        $('.collapse').collapse('show');
        $('#job-summ-panel').html(response.jobs)
    },                               
});
```

Jobs will initially be empty when they first load the page so it wont display anything. I dont get how to refresh/reload the div and do the foreach again with the new response data.

Comment: You will need to loop over the jobs via javaScript not via laravel foreach !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this. First, is server-side generation, and second is client-side application.

### 1. Server side content generation

You might want to move that part of the page to a different blade template. Then with a AJAX call, you can rebuild the page and send the output to the browser. For example:

**Route Definition**

```
Route::post("generateList", "Partials@generateList");
```

**Partial Template Definition**

> Partials\loopContainer.blade.php

```
<div class="col-lg-6 collapse" >
    <div class="job-summ-panel" id="job-summ-panel" >
        @foreach($jobs as $job)
            {{$job['active']}}
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
```

**Your Partial Content Generator**

```
<?php 

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    class Partials extends Controller {

    public function generateList(Request $request){
        // generate data from the parameters again
        $input = $request->input('job_ref');
        $generatedData = GenerateDataFromJobRef($input);
        return View::make("partials/loopContainer", ["jobs" => $generatedData]);
    }
?>
```

**Client Side Refresh**

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: '/generateList',
    data: {
        job_ref: marker.getCustomData('job_ref'),
    },
    success: function (response) {
        $('.collapse').collapse('show');
        $('#job-summ-panel').html(response)
    },                               
});
```

### 2. Client side content application

**Route Definition**

```
Route::post("generateList", "Partials@generateList");
```

**Your Partial Content Generator**

```
<?php 

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    class Partials extends Controller {

    public function generateList(Request $request){
        // generate data from the parameters again
        $input = $request->input('job_ref');
        $generatedData = GenerateDataFromJobRef($input);
        return json_encode(["data" => $generatedData]);
    }
?>
```

**Client Side Refresh**

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: '/generateList',
    data: {
        job_ref: marker.getCustomData('job_ref'),
    },
    success: function (response) {
        $('.collapse').collapse('show');            
        var appendString = "";
        for(var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++){
            appendString += "<div>" + response.data[i].info + "</div>";    
        }
        $('#job-summ-panel').empty().append(appendString);
    },                               
});
```

Comment: I see thank you, that makes sense to make a separate template.