# Reload HTML After Post Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-blade

I've been trying to reload a portion of the page after the user created a post.

**JavaScript**

```
success: function(result)
{
    $("#postsxd").load(" #postsxd");
    console.log(result);
}
```

**Blade**

```php
@foreach(Auth::user()->posts()->latest()->paginate(1) as $userpost)
    <div class="ui-block" id="postsxd">
        <article class="hentry post">
            <div class="post__author author vcard inline-items">
                <img src="{{ $userpost->user->getFirstMediaUrl('pps') ? $userpost->user->getFirstMediaUrl('pps')  : '/img/ava_10.jpg' }}"
                     width="36" height="36" alt="author">
                <div class="author-date">
                    <a class="h6 post__author-name fn" href="#">{{ $userpost->author }}</a>
                    <label style="font-size: 12px;">(Your latest post)</label>
                    <div class="post__date">
                        <time class="published" datetime="2004-07-24T18:18">9 hours ago</time>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p>{!! $userpost->content !!}</p>
        </article>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

I don't know why the page does not reload that element or what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance for the help.

Also, how can I change a button after the user submits the form or clicks it?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46765438/reload-laravel-foreach-after-ajax

Comment: Have you tried `$("#postsxd").load( "you_file_name.html");`

Answer (score 0):

Add `foreach` loop in a `div` tag and give a unique id to that div tag and use that tag in the javascript file.

Code :

**Blade File**

```
<div id="#uniqueId">

    @foreach(Auth::user()->posts()->latest()->paginate(1) as $userpost)
        <div class="ui-block" id="postsxd">
            <article class="hentry post">
                <div class="post__author author vcard inline-items">
                    <img src="{{ $userpost->user->getFirstMediaUrl('pps') ? $userpost->user->getFirstMediaUrl('pps')  : '/img/ava_10.jpg' }}"
                         width="36" height="36" alt="author">
                    <div class="author-date">
                        <a class="h6 post__author-name fn" href="#">{{ $userpost->author }}</a>
                        <label style="font-size: 12px;">(Your latest post)</label>
                        <div class="post__date">
                            <time class="published" datetime="2004-07-24T18:18">9 hours ago</time>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p>{!! $userpost->content !!}</p>
            </article>
        </div>
    @endforeach

</div>
```

**JavaScript | Ajax Responce**

```
success: function(result)
{
    $("#uniqueId").load(" #uniqueId > *");
    console.log(result);
}
```