# How to increment a model attribute count?

Tags: ajax, laravel

I'm trying to make a very simple blog using Laravel and Ajax, each blog post has likes so i want to increment the likes by clicking and updating the DB also in console there is no errors.

this is my schema :

```
Schema::create('blogs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->longText('blogContent');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->integer('likes')->default(8);
        });
```

here's my blade template and script :

```
@section('content')
  <div class="myFeedContainer col-lg-9 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
      @foreach ($blogs as $blog)
      <div class='blogContainer'>
            <h5 class='blogTitle'>{{$blog->title}}</h5>
            <h6 class='blogDate'>{{$blog->created_at}}</h6>
            <p class='blogContent1' >{{$blog->blogContent}}</p>
            <hr>
            <h6 class='blogLikes' class="clickforlikes" data-id='{{$blog->id}}'>
              {{$blog->likes}} 
              <ion-icon name="heart" ></ion-icon>
            </h6>      

            <br>
        </div>
      @endforeach

      <div id='pagina'>{{ $blogs->render() }}</div>

      <script>
        $('.clickforlikes').on("click", function(){
          $.ajax({
            url:'updateLikes',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
              blog_id: $(this).attr('data-id')
            },
            success: function (data){
              console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(request, stqtus, error){
              console.log('code: ' + request.status + '\n' + 'msg: '+request.responseText+'\n'+'error: ' + error);
            }
          });
        });

    </script>
  </div>    
@endsection
```

And this is the function from my controller

```
  public function updateLikes()
  {
    $blog_Id = $_POST['blog_id'];
    $blog = Blog::find($blog_Id)->increment('likes');
    $blog->save();
  }
```

This is the router :

```
Route::post('/updateLikes', 'BlogsController@updateLikes');
```

Comment: What is the actual error?

Comment: `$blog_Id = $_POST['blog_id'];` you should use request validation https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic

Comment: side note: you don't need to call `save`, `increment` runs a query to update the record and syncs the attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to accomplish this the PHP way. Since you are using a framework, you should take advantage of its cool features. In Laravel, you would have to do something like this:

Router:

```
Route::put('updateLikes/{id}', 'BlogsController@updateLikes');
```

Controller:

```
public function updateLikes($id) { $blog = Blog::find($id)->increment('likes'); $blog->save(); }
```

Ajax call:

```
<script> $('.clickforlikes').on("click", function(){ $.ajax({ url:'updateLikes/'+$(this).attr('data-id'), type: 'PUT', success: function (data){ console.log(data); }, error: function(request, stqtus, error){ console.log('code: ' + request.status + '\n' + 'msg: '+request.responseText+'\n'+'error: ' + error); } }); }); </script>
```

The HTTP method is different because a POST request is meant to be used to create a new resource in the database. On the other hand, PUT is used to update a resource. Your ajax request will call the route with the id of the blog appended to it, and the controller will get the id as a parameter and perform the update.

Comment: I've done all that you said but i'm getting this error from Ajax:  PUT http://127.0.0.1:8000/updateLikes/undefined 500 (Internal Server Error), I also added <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}"> and ajaxSetup

Comment: The problem might be that `$(this).attr('data-id')` is not holding the ID of the post. Are you sure that you are getting the value correctly? Also, in your Route make sure you have **PUT** instead of **POST**.

Comment: I fixed the 500 error now I got this `jquery.min.js:2 PUT http://127.0.0.1:8000/updateLikes/7     404 (Not Found)`

I even changed `$(this).attr('data-id')` to `$(this).data('id')` still got the same error

Comment: Great! So you are now getting the **id** passed correctly. That 404 error probably means that your route cannot be found, so maybe you have a problem in defining your route. I think the problem might be the extra '/' in your route definition. Try modifying this:

`Route::put('updateLikes/{id}', 'BlogsController@updateLikes');`

Comment: Awesome it's all working now ! any suggestion on how to reload the blog post so it get the update without reloading the whole page ? Thank you so much

Comment: Good to know :) Since you are using Server Side Rendering, updating the value in the view is kind of tricky. I think your best shot is returning a partial page after updating the blog in your controller. Here is a thread that could help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46765438/reload-laravel-foreach-after-ajax?rq=1

If you had a SPA using any of the current top frameworks (React, Angular, Vue) this would be a piece of cake.

Answer (score 0):

You are using POST method. You can receive these data by Request Service Container in `updateLikes()` method.

```
public function updateLikes(Request $request)
{
    $blog_Id = $request->get('blog_id');
    $blog = Blog::find($blog_Id)->increment('likes');
    // other codes if needed
}
```