# set selected value in dropdown when update data in laravel using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have dropdown like this:

```
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">{{ __('Product Plan') }}<span class="required"></span></label>

                            <select name="product_plan" class="form-control" id="product_plan" style="width: 50%">
                                @foreach ($product_plan as $val)
                                    <option value="{{ $val->productplanID }}">
                                        {{ $val->productplanID }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I using modal to update this data, so I use AJAX. This is my ajax method for get the data:

```
$('body').on('click', '.editPlanSchedule', function() {
var Item_id = $(this).data('id');
$.get("/quotation/getEditPlanSchedule" + '/' + Item_id, function(data) {
    $('#product_plan').val(data.product_plan);
    // console.log(data.product_plan);
})
```

});

I get the data correctly. My question is, how to put the selected value in select option from database using ajax? I try console.log(data.product_plan), I get the data. But when I do $('#product_plan').val(data.product_plan);, select option not selected the correct select from database.

Comment: I think this can help you: [Reload laravel foreach after ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46765438/reload-laravel-foreach-after-ajax)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.editPlanSchedule', function() {
var Item_id = $(this).data('id');
$.get("/quotation/getEditPlanSchedule" + '/' + Item_id, function(data) {
    let options = "";
    data.product_plan.forEach(p => {
        options += `<option value="${p.productplanID}">${p.productplanID}</option>`;
    }
    $('#product_plan').val(options);
})
});
```